# How to efficiently implement a groupby and subsequent rolling apply over time using pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data of purchases over time. Each purchase belongs to a user and a subgroup. Additionally, each purchase has a date. What I would like to achieve is to apply a rolling function (using the dates) on the profit column for each combination of user and subgroup.

Below I created a standalone example with the pandas solution to my problem and the pyspark solution to my problem. The question I have now is: **is there a more efficient way of doing this in pyspark?**

Stand-alone example:

```
# Create some dummy date
date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(250), freq='D')

np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'dates': days, 'profit': data,'user':1,'subgroup':np.random.randint(0,5,len(days))})

days = pd.date_range(date_today+ timedelta(hours = 5), date_today + timedelta(130), freq='D')
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'dates': days, 'profit': data,'user':2,'subgroup':np.random.randint(0,5,len(days))})

df_all = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

Pandas solution:

```
df_agg = df_all.groupby(by = ["user","subgroup"]).apply(lambda df: df.set_index('dates').rolling("20d").agg({"profit":[np.mean,np.max]}))
```

Slow pySpark solution:

```
sdf_all = spark.createDataFrame(df_all)

days = lambda i: i * 86400 
sdf_output = (sdf_all.withColumn("profit_mean",F.avg(F.col("profit"))
                                        .over(Window.partitionBy("user","subgroup")
                                        .orderBy(F.col("dates").cast("long"))
                                        .rangeBetween(-days(20),0)))
                     .withColumn("profit_max",F.max(F.col("profit"))
                                        .over(Window.partitionBy("user","subgroup")
                                        .orderBy(F.col("dates").cast("long"))
                                        .rangeBetween(-days(20),0)))

             )
```